# Disable BUTTON_POSITIVE throws null pointer

Tags: android

I want to disable the positive button on a dialog, but I am unable to. Here is my dialog:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.delete_db_on_exit)
        .setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                _application.setDeleteDatabaseOnExit();
                dialog.cancel();
                //Navigate back to main activity
            }
        })
        .create();

dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
dialog.show();
```

Even though I *just* set the Positive button, when I reference it, I get a null pointer exception. Is this because of where I referenced it? Was there a major change to the Android dialogs that was not noted in their documentation?

I am noticing that I am unable to do anything they have noted in their current [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 0):

**What I understand from  your question is**:: *You are trying to cancel the dialog onclick of positive button in the dialog.*

---

**Instead of**::

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.delete_db_on_exit)
            .setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    _application.setDeleteDatabaseOnExit();
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //Navigate back to main activity
                }
            })
            .create();

    dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
    dialog.show();
```

**Try this** ::

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.delete_db_on_exit)
            .setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .create();

    dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
    dialog.show();
```

**Also Place your code  after the dialog call ....**

```
_application.setDeleteDatabaseOnExit();
//Navigate back to main activity
```

**I think you cannot place it inside the dialog button action(if possible use a flag)** *Hope it helps !*

Comment: Hey Devrath! The issue I am is that the `dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);` line will throw a null pointer exception, because there is no `BUTTON_POSITIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call `getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)` after `dialog.show()`

FROM:

```
 dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
 dialog.show();
```

TO:

```
dialog.show();
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```